# Delete all except the latest unique combinations of two columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table variable that I need to delete rows from.  This query shows the contents of the table:

```
SELECT
    useractionId,
    userId,
    actionId,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, actionId ORDER BY dateOfApplication ASC) AS applicationOrder, -- put into order of application (earliest first)
    dateOfApplication
FROM
    @tbl_appliedhistory;
```

The results are as follows, and provide a record of each time a user has completed an action:

**EDIT - Added extra row at the end where there is only one userid/actionid combination**

```
useractionId userId     actionId    applicationOrder     dateOfApplication
----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------------------
7665        3           2479        1                    2013-09-08 18:17:23.953
7675        3           2479        2                    2013-09-08 18:18:56.063
7685        3           2479        3                    2013-09-08 18:21:21.487
8286        3           2695        1                    2013-11-07 09:28:03.817
8287        3           2695        2                    2013-11-11 13:47:11.337
8289        3           2695        3                    2013-11-11 13:47:56.390
8291        3           2695        4                    2013-11-11 13:48:11.957
8284        87453       2695        1                    2013-11-06 15:08:40.823
8285        87453       2695        2                    2013-11-06 15:09:26.167
8288        87453       2695        3                    2013-11-11 13:47:11.337
8290        87453       2695        4                    2013-11-11 13:47:56.390
8291        89000       3000        1                    2013-11-12 15:50:50.000
```

For each combination of `userId`/`actionId` column values, I need to delete all but the highest value of `applicationOrder` (the latest completed action of that particular `actionId`).  So, once deleted, the remaining rows would be:

```
useractionId  userId    actionId    applicationOrder     dateOfApplication
----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------- -----------------------
7685        3           2479        3                    2013-09-08 18:21:21.487
8291        3           2695        4                    2013-11-11 13:48:11.957
8290        87453       2695        4                    2013-11-11 13:47:56.390
8291        89000       3000        1                    2013-11-12 15:50:50.000
```

These results show the latest dates that a user completed each action.  I would appreciate any help in identifying those rows please.

Comment: Is there any possibility that multiple rows with the same `userId` and `actionId` will *also* have the same `applicationOrder` - or are the three values taken together effectively a key for this table?

Comment: No, `Row_Number OVER (PARITION BY ...)` should stop that happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example, instead of ORDER BY dateOfApplication ASC used the ORDER BY dateOfApplication DESC.

```
;WITH cte AS
 (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, actionId ORDER BY dateOfApplication DESC) AS applicationOrder
  FROM Table1
  )
DELETE cte
WHERE applicationOrder != 1
```

Demo on [`SQLFIddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d58b/2)

Comment: What would happen if there was only one combination of a particular userid/actionid (see additional) row in my post.  `ApplicationOrder` here would always be 1 if there was only one combination, and that would need retaining in the results.

Comment: As you want this line will be saved in the results

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just order by dateOfApplication **desc**, and then delete all with row_number > 1 ?

Like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
     SELECT
         useractionId,
         userId,
         actionId,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, actionId ORDER BY dateOfApplication DESC) AS applicationOrder, -- put into order of application (earliest first)
         dateOfApplication
     FROM @tbl_appliedhistory
)

DELETE FROM CTE WHERE applicationOrder > 1
```

Comment: As above, what would happen if there was only one combination of a particular userid/actionid (see additional) row in my post.  `ApplicationOrder` here would always be 1 if there was only one combination.

Comment: @EvilDr: Then it wouldn't delete it, because it shouldn't delete the latest one.

Comment: Ah yes sorry of course, because we're now showing results in descending order.  Love it - thanks!